# divergent subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In my real analysis course, I'am confused about something.
Our professor told us that a sequence that is unbounded from above has a subsequence that diverges to + infinity. however if we find a sequence that has a subsequence that diverges to + infinity, does that mean that this sequence is unbounded from above?

I know that if p implies q, then this does not mean that q implies p.

Comment: Well... what would be an upper bound of the whole sequence?

Comment: P implies q does not imply that q implies p.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence (or subsequence, doesn't matter) $a_n$ diverges to $+\infty$ means that for all $M$ there exists $N=N(M)\in\mathbb N$ such that $n>N$ implies $a_n>M$. If the sequence were bounded from above by some $M$ then for all $n>N(M)$ (for example, $n=N(M)+1$) we'd have both $a_n>M$ and $a_n\le M$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it must be true. If you can find a subsequence that diverges to $\infty$ then you can always find a point from that sequence that is greater than any given value, hence it cannot be bounded from above.